# I can't bigram a sentece with Python3

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, n-gram

I'm using python3 and i'm traing to bigram a sentence but the interpreter gives me a problem that i can't understand.

```
~$ python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.util import ngrams
>>> text = "Hi How are you? i am fine and you"
>>> token=nltk.word_tokenize(text)
>>> bigrams=ngrams(token,2)
>>> bigrams
<generator object ngrams at 0x7ff1d81d2468>
>>> print (bigrams)
<generator object ngrams at 0x7ff1d81d2468>
```

What does it means: "generator object ngrams at 0x7ff1d81d2468"?
Why I can neither inspect nor print n-grams?

Comment: Try `print(list(bigrams))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator objects are iterable, but only once - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1756156). When `print` tries to display them, it shows their type rather than their actual 'items'. You can convert the generator object into a list using

```
>>> bigrams=list(ngrams(token,2))
```

and them print their items using

```
>>> print(bigrams)
```

as they are now a list object, so their items are printed instead of 'description' of them.